# How to get the code that made .append() function?

Tags: python, function

I want to append an int to a list like that

```
x = []
x.append(5)
```

but I don't want to use any built-in functions. so how can I get its source code so that I can know the algorithm

Comment: That’s not a built-in function, that is a *method* on the list type. The list type is implemented in native code as part of the CPython source.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically the operator `+=`

```
l = [4] 
l += [5]
l
```

Returns `[4,5]`

```
l = ["str1"] 
l += ["str2"]
l += [None]
l
```

Returns  `['str1', 'str2', None]`

Comment: and if  i want to append a string?

Comment: @KareemMohamed it is the same for strings

Comment: thanks alot. can i ask for removing or poping string or int?

Comment: @KareemMohamed you can use slicing. so the element you want to remove idx = 1then you l = l[:idx]+l[idx+1:]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2396614b8958ad202378fd71a598eb4106ac5896/Objects/listobject.c#L834

```c
/*[clinic input]
list.append
     object: object
     /
Append object to the end of the list.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
list_append(PyListObject *self, PyObject *object)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=7c096003a29c0eae input=43a3fe48a7066e91]*/
{
    if (app1(self, object) == 0)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    return NULL;
}
```

However, `list` is a built-in type, so it's literally impossible not to use *any* built-in functions/methods while using lists.